# In vba Find the value in column by Color RGB(255,199, 206) and Write the single Value as "Duplicate" in next column

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, highlight, conditional-formatting

In vba Find the value in column by Color RGB(255,199, 206) and Write the single Value as "Duplicate" in next column.
Please view the snap for more understanding.

[image]

I am trying below code to highlight the Cells
and then I wanted to use new code to print "duplicate" infront of highlighted cells .
Can you please guide me .

```
Sub Highlight_Duplicate_Value()

Columns("AD:AD").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
.Color = -16383844
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.Color = 13551615
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Note this only checks interior color.

```
Sub colorcheck()
Dim Checkrange As Range
Dim cell As Range
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row
Set Checkrange = ActiveSheet.Range("AD1:AD" & lastrow)
    For Each cell In Checkrange
    
If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = 13551615 Then
cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Duplicate"

End If
```

Comment: Thank You for this code, Just one update What if I want to print "Duplicate" at specific column, For example I want to print "Duplicate" in Column AE.

Comment: cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Duplicate" this is already doing it.   Offset moves destination (rows,columns) from the original(checked cell), in this case one column right from the original cell.Offset(0, 2).Value would be AF etc.